# How to get a number as user input and use in while loop to print Fibonacci number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the following to print Fibonacci numbers.

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 200:
       print b,
       a, b = b, a+b
```

In the above program, I want to take the number `200` as user input. I tried the following:

```
a, b = 0, 1

while b < (int(raw_input("Enter a number : "))):
       print b,
       a, b = b, a+b
```

If I run the above script, it asks for input two times and prints nothing as shown below:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop>python fib.py
Enter a number : 200
1 Enter a number : 1

C:\Users\test\Desktop>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

If `raw_input` is in the condition of your `while`, then it will prompt the user for input every single time you go through the loop. If you only want to prompt the user exactly once, put it before the loop.

```
a, b = 0, 1

limit = int(raw_input("Enter a number : "))
while b < limit:
       print b,
       a, b = b, a+b
```

Result:

```
Enter a number : 200
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144
```